# Issue on Resting Select Options in Bootstrap Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap Select Plugin I have a select options list at [This Demo](http://www.bootply.com/eL80iOq5Uk) . Now I would like to reset the select option to First option ("Select From The List") when ever user Clicks on Reset btn. I already tried this:

```
$('#resetForm').on("click", function(){
 $("#selopt").val($("#selopt option:first").val());
});

<select class="selectpicker" id="selopt">
    <option value="0">Select From List</option>
    <option value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="2">Saab</option>
    <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="resetForm" class="btn btn-success">Reset</button>
```

but this is not doing the job! Can you please let me know how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 'deselect' to reset your selectpicker as:

```
$('#resetForm').on("click", function(){
    **$("#selopt").selectpicker('deselectAll');**
});
<select class="selectpicker" id="selopt">
    <option value="0">Select From List</option>
    <option value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="2">Saab</option>
    <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Reset

Hope this helps